# Creating Ref<T> from Ref<TU, TK>

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following type:

```
type Ref<T2, TK extends keyof T2> = [T2, TK];
```

How can I create a type where `T2[TK] = T`?

I know I can do the following:

```
type Ref<T extends T2[TK], T2, TK extends keyof T2> = [T2, TK];
```

but then I have to specify `Ref<T, T2, TK>` and I want only to specify `Ref<T>`.

**EDIT:**

You can see my code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-beta#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmAJgUwB7IE4wLwwMoCeAtgEYgA2AFAEQDaAutQJQDcAUG1AQA7IwBKyAGYAeACoA%20HGwDebGApiUmALhhj2ipQDcAhuQCuyNWNXr2AXw4IomIbuB8AasmBQQGAEyy2ASAAaamAGpJiaigCaQSEkYWxWbMDkuhAQMC5uHt5yWtC6UHDAMADCGMj5fJSo0aEYADQwBDWxGGYZ7l4wMjBlUAYYYF2BMKgNUY0WMFYJSSlpAIIYGLoEAOrL3LwY4hI%20WqCQUBgGmViU3AYk5IXwtkQQJgxMXQm%20tAgo6Bj0lB9ozZgzIJRJIuj1kH0BjoAPwmZ7YKTaHDYXAGJDCBDIRAwaEwKAACzgEAAdHA7hB3ujUPQYGoCUTSeTKZ8abgkdMOOQITBdEs1ItlmsNlsRO0slJcGBkAB3GAClbrXSbTCUWhirzE0rlWyUADMDQALEwGurPJqyhU9Q0AKxMeisNi8jDMtCYH4ARiYymJ-hwMAN7AOEAoyGJ5BAAHNKE6XV8PV6mD7WEA).

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want a generic type that, when instantiated with a given type, finds a particular object type and key where the member of that interface at that key has the given type. Without more context, it sounds like this would be impossible. Consider, for example, `Ref<number>`, which would need to randomly choose from all `number` members of all object types known to the compiler.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete usage exampe of `Ref<T, T2, TK>` type?

Comment: @aleksxor, I added a link to my code on my answer.

Comment: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nalz0w) here is an example usage of this `Ref<T, T2, TK>` type but i really don't get how are you supposing to get the same result providing only `Ref<number>`. Can you show usage example of that kind of Ref and expected result?

Comment: @aleksxor, You can see an example I would expect to work here: https://tsplay.dev/mxoKBN